# output picklist field in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputfield

I would like to display a field (picklist) in my lightning component and then get the users value and apply some logic to it. At the moment I have hard coded the picklist as seen below:

```
    <lightning:select name="selectItem" label="test1" aura:id="testid" required="true">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
        <option value="option3">option3</option>
    </lightning:select>
```

I would know like to actually reference the picklist field and show that in my component with the Lightning style. I already have the logic behind the scenes working.

I am trying different tags e.g. force:outputField or the lightning and ui versions. The issue I am having is since I already have a Apex controller, how do I reference the picklist field (I assume I have to reference the custom object the field is from)?

If I try use something like below, it will not know which object the field I am referencing is coming from. And I don't think this approch will display all the values in the picklist (maybe use some inputSelect tag?).

```
<aura:component controller="customApexController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">

 <lightning:input aura:id="test1" label="test picklist"
                         name="some name"
                         value="{!v.mypicklist}"
                         required="true"/>
```

Comment: Are you planning on using your component in all those interfaces?

Comment: @glls I could and probably should clean that up a little. I don't need some of those interfaces

Comment: You posted a basic code sample of a picklist, maybe you can update your post with how you would assign values from your server side apex controller to your lightning component?